# Using Solr packages in standalone mode

Tags: solr

I have Solr in standalone mode (as opposed to the cloud). When I try to use packages, it tries to use cloud mode (by connecting to zookeeper),

```
/opt/solr/bin/solr package list-available
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:190)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:122)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:109)
    at org.apache.solr.packagemanager.PackageManager.<init>(PackageManager.java:85)
    at org.apache.solr.util.PackageTool.runImpl(PackageTool.java:85)
    at org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI$ToolBase.runTool(SolrCLI.java:196)
    at org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI.main(SolrCLI.java:304)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ConnectStringParser.<init>(ConnectStringParser.java:54)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.createDefaultHostProvider(ZooKeeper.java:1515)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:1108)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:818)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZooKeeper.<init>(SolrZooKeeper.java:44)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkClientConnectionStrategy.createSolrZooKeeper(ZkClientConnectionStrategy.java:109)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.DefaultConnectionStrategy.connect(DefaultConnectionStrategy.java:37)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.<init>(SolrZkClient.java:168)
    ... 7 more

ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

this is the status of the running instance:

```
/opt/solr/bin/solr status

Found 1 Solr nodes: 

Solr process 525452 running on port 8983
{
  "solr_home":"/var/solr/data",
  "version":"8.9.0 05c8a6f0163fe4c330e93775e8e91f3ab66a3f80 - mayyasharipova - 2021-06-10 17:54:40",
  "startTime":"2021-09-17T19:00:43.284Z",
  "uptime":"31 days, 23 hours, 48 minutes, 27 seconds",
  "memory":"43.2 MB (%8.4) of 512 MB"}
```